# How can I prevent from mutating the style object in a div?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I am getting the following error:

> Warning: `div` was passed a style object that has previously been
>   mutated. Mutating `style` is deprecated. Consider cloning it
>   beforehand. Check the `render` of `Tab`. Previous style: `{padding:
>   "20px", display: "block"}`. Mutated style: `{padding: "20px", display:
>   "none"}`.

From this code in my `render()` method in React/JSX:

```
const clonedChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (el, i) => {
  let visibility = 'none';
  if (i === this.state.activeIndex) visibility = 'block';
  const newStyle = { display: visibility };
  const style = Object.assign(el.props.style, newStyle);
  return React.cloneElement(el, { style });
});
```

Why is this error happening? I am already cloning the element. How can I fix this?

Comment: you forgot the empty object as the first parameter: ` Object.assign({}, el.props.style, newStyle);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't mutate your `el.props.style`. Currently you're using `Object.assign` and mutating `el.props.style` by using it as the target object. Instead, use `Object.assign` and use a new object as the target:

```
const style = Object.assign({}, el.props.style, newStyle);
```

This will not mutate `el.props.style`. It will instead mutate the new object `{}`. Further reading on `Object.assign` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: Darn, you're right! Forgot curly braces.. T.T thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It told me that I had to wait until I can accept. I guess you were a little to fast with your answer :-) - Accepted it is!